# Приостановка приложения в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Как остановить ход выполнения программы в Delphi до нажатия пользователем клавиши (допустим, любой) без вызова дополнительного окна?

То есть пусть есть 10 строк кода. Первые 5 строк выполнились и программа ждёт действий пользователя. Тот нажимает, допустим, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, и далее выполняются остальные 5 строк кода. Ах, да, всё это происходит не в консольном приложении (а что делать в консольном, кроме `readln`?).

p.s.
Извините, если не точно выразился, но `MessageBox` и `ShowMessage` не подходят.
Остановка за счёт свойств и методов формы подойдёт только, если её можно сделать динамически. (По этому поводу другой мой вопрос: [Работа с TForm в Delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/30200))

Comment: А может цикл поставить где нужно, в ожидании нажатии нужной (любой) клавиши? Как нажал, цикл прекращается и поехали дальше.

Comment: Буду очень благодарен за код данного цикла или хотя бы, что в нём писать (суть). Прочтите пожалуйста мой комментарий на первый ответ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Из простых способов: выводить `ShowMessage(...)` в местах, где нужна пауза. Остановит поток выполнения и закроется нажатием Enter.

---

Простые способы кончились, перейдем к непростым.

Вам нужно написать процедуру паузы следующего вида:

```
procedure TMyForm.Pause;
begin
  FPaused := true;
  while FPaused do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Где, FPaused - поле класса TMyForm. Бесконечная пауза обрабатывающая события есть. Теперь нам нужно обрабатывать нажатия клавиш.

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
     FPaused : boolean;
     procedure WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown); message WM_KEYDOWN;
     procedure Pause;
     ....
  end;
...
procedure TMyForm.WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown); 
begin
   FPaused := false;
 end;
```

Обработчик будет сбрасывать флаг FPaused, и, когда управление вернется в процедуру Pause, бесконечный цикл завершит свою работу.

Comment: И вам, конечно, спасибо за ответ. Но ShowMessage я уже сделал. А, как я уже говорил, необходимо обойтись без вызова второго окна, чем ShowMessage, собственно и является.
Второй вариант тоже хорош, но не подходит. Почему - смотрите мой комментарий на предыдущий ответ.

Comment: Да, с вынесением в отдельный компонент будет заморочка.

Answer (score 1):

Написать обработчик события `OnKeyPress`, `OnKeyDown` или `OnKeyUp` на выбор.

А в консольном `readln`-а более чем достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ваш вариант подходит, когда приложение пишет 1 человек. Мне же необходимо написать такой метод моего класса, при вызове которого другой программист "остановит своё приложение".

Comment: Это относится к ответу Nofate-а
`procedure WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown); message WM_KEYDOWN;` можно поставить в любой класс это событие сработает при нажатии клавиши.

Answer (score 1):

```
// какой-то код ...
if Application.MessageBox('Продолжить?', 'Вопрос', MB_OKCANCEL) = ID_OK then
begin
  // какой-то после нажатия OK ...
end;
```

Comment: Но ведь, `MessageBox` - это ещё одно окно.

Answer (score 1):

Есть более простой и красивый способ. Процедуру, в которой нужно сделать "паузу", разбиваем на две части - до и после паузы (понятно, что это не всегда возможно, но в многих случаях вполне реально).
После того, как первая половинка выполнилась, она выставляет некий флаг, что бы знать об этом. Дальше, в процедуре обработки нажатия клавиш или той, которая обработает от пользователя запрос на продолжение - выполнить вторую процедуру.

Если параметров нужно передать много, то просто делаем структуру (record), в который вставляем все параметры и передаем в каждую процедуру.

Comment: Это как раз не очень красивый с точки зрения проектирования способ. Что если у нас несколько таких процедур, которые надо разбить? Что если у нас несколько пауз в процедуре? Что если решение о паузе нужно принять исходя из каких-то внешних данных (например загружаем циклично некоторые ресурсы, количество и состав которых заранее не известен, и делаем паузы при сбоях)? ТС, похоже, хочет обобщенное решение, которое можно использовать в любом месте по желанию.

Comment: Давайте подождем TC и не будет делать неверных предположений. Если же пауз несколько - а в чем то проблема? Сделать несколько процедур? Но если страшно, есть ещё один чудный способ тело процедуры - один большой case. и одна глобальная переменная (или поле класса), которая хранит текущее состояние.

Comment: Извините, не понял, что есть "вторая процедура". Вот, что, предположительно необходимо: 
`// пишет программистN приложение `
`...  `
`// что-то отобразилось  `
`MyClass.Stop; // вызывает остановку из объекта моего класса,  `
`// это и есть процедура, которую надо разбить?`

Comment: Получается так. При этом собственно `MyClass.Stop` уже не будет. То есть было: процедураХ, код1, стоп, код2; стало: процедураХ1, код1, сохранить флаг, что процедура отработала. процедураХ2, проверить флаг, код2.

Comment: но ведь так получается, что это всё пишет программист, который использует мой класс(?)  
а мне хотелось бы позаботиться об остановке самому

Comment: просто у "стоп" слишком большая абстракция. Для чего останавливается "приложение", как планируется запускать дальше? Если к примеру по нажатию клавиши, то придется как то либо перехватывать ввод, либо получать колбеки.
В целом - уточните, и получите более точное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Когда мне нужно просто приостановить программу (например, для цветового эффекта) на заданное время, я пользуюсь заранее прописанной процедурой Pauser (в interface-uses-списке pas-файл, там размещены мои процедуры и функции, которыми я часто пользуюсь в своём нехитром программировании):

```
procedure Pauser(MSec:word);
var t: Cardinal;
begin
  t:=GetMSec;
  repeat  Until GetMSec > t+MSec;
end;

function GetMSec:Cardinal;
begin
  result:=CurTime;
end;

function  CurTime: cardinal;
var
  Hour, Min, Sec, MSec: word;
begin
  DecodeTime(Time, Hour, Min, Sec, MSec);        
  result:= (Hour*3600+Min*60+Sec)*1000+MSec;
end;
```