# Создать класс на основе TForm, с методами типа: OnClick, MouseDown и т.д. без привязки к приложению

Tags: delphi

Необходимо создать класс на основе TForm (или класс, содержащий такой компонент) так, чтобы были написаны методы типа: OnClick, MouseDown и т.д. без привязки к приложению. Яснее говоря, сам пытался и получается либо класс TForm1 с приложением, либо класс на основе TForm, но без нужных методов (см. выше).

То есть чтобы другой программист при создании объекта моего класса вызвал форму с реакцией на данные события.

После запуска и нажатия на Button1 вылазит сообщение "Resource MyForm not found". Понятия не имею, что делать. Нет только кода Prject, но он стандартный

```
unit Unit1;  
interface  
uses  
...   
type  
  MyForm = class(TForm) // мой класс 
    procedure Click; override;  
  end;  
  TForm1 = class(TForm)  // форма для application
    Button1: TButton;  
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
  end;  
var  
  Form1: TForm1;  
  f: MyForm;  
implementation  
{$R *.dfm}  
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
  f := MyForm.Create(f/self);  
end;  
{новый клик}  
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@gecube](/users/907/gecube)](/users/907/gecube) Наверное, просто незнание того, как это сделать.

`OnClick`, `OnMouseDown` вызываются из процедур `Click` и `MouseDown` - нужно просто заменить их в вашем классе.

Вот упрошенный пример для Click-а

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
  protected
    { Private declarations }
    procedure Click;override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TmyForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Click;
begin
  ShowMessage('dasdsa');

  inherited ;
end;
```

Comment: спасибо, вероятно, то, что нужно. (реализую - отмечу)  
а какие ещё, кроме Click, можно переопределить?  
(или просто убираем "On" - и так, как в вашем примере)

Comment: В принципе почти все просто убираем "On".

Ну а если правильно действовать пройдись по предкам класса TForm

найди функцию в котором реализован вызов обработчика события и переопредели ее.

А еше лучше почитай про основы ООП.

Comment: после запуска и нажатия на Button1 вылазит сообщение "Resource MyForm not found". Понятия не имею, что делать. Нет только кода Prject, но он стандартный  
unit Unit1;  
interface  
uses  
...   
type  
  MyForm = class(TForm) // мой класс 
    procedure Click; override;  
  end;  
  TForm1 = class(TForm)  // форма для application
    Button1: TButton;  
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
  end;  
var  
  Form1: TForm1;  
  f: MyForm;  
implementation  
{$R *.dfm}  
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
  f := MyForm.Create(f/self);  
end;  
{новый клик}  
end.

Comment: Для формы нужен еше dfm файл, поэтому делать 2 формы в одном юните - это слишком геморойно, лучше сделать 2 юнита с формами, потом их отредактировать. Или отредактируйте dfm, чтоб там описание MyForm класса было (но это кучу других проблем создаст).

Вот работающий исходник http://files.mail.ru/J50C5X. Версия делфей 2010.